# Adding password protection to an Excel file (not a copy of the file)

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple Excel files in a folder that I need to password protect with unique passwords.

My objective is to password protect the files without manually opening them to apply the password.

```vb
With wslist
    
    For i = first_row To last_row - 1
    
        'Worksheets("Processing File").Cells(i, 4) = Worksheets("Home_Page").Cells(i, 5).Value
    
        file_name = Worksheets("Home_Page").Cells(i, 6).Value
        temp_password = Worksheets("Home_Page").Cells(i, 7).Value
    
        'ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs filename:=file_name, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        Set masterWB = Workbooks.Open(file_name)
        masterWB.Password = temp_password
        masterWB.Close savechanges:=True
    
    Next i
     
End With
```

This code opens a dialog box asking to save a copy of the file.

For example if I have a "File1" in the folder this asks me to save it as a copy of File1 instead of password protecting the original file.

Comment: Save As the file in a temporary folder and get the code to delete the original file. Then move the new files in the original folder

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad But why?

Comment: @FunThomas I _think_ that you _need_ to use a save as to change something like adding a password to a file. This is the method I have always used when having to do this kind of task and no other has ever presented itself to me

Comment: That method is what's shown in the docs for `Workbook.Password` and works for me, so are the files maybe being opened as read-only?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.password

Comment: Thank you so much for the responses everyone!
@TimWilliams: I believe that might be the issue. Do you know how I can overcome this? I just want to make sure that I don't have to manually save as for each file in the folder

Comment: Try passing `ReadOnly:=False` when opening the files